# SQL Dynamic Pivot question to identify multiple records belonging to individual customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I hoping some can offer some advise for SSMS DBS.

I need to be able to create a dynamic pivot based upon adding columns to a table containing policy numbers belonging to a specific person.  e.g transforming this

| Client_id | Policynumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123A |
| 1 | 234 |
| 1 | 445 |
| 2 | 999 |
| 3 | 111 |
| 3 | 222 |

Into this - the scenarios could be that a customers has 1 or 50 policies and so has to be dynamic

| Client_id | Policynumber1 | Policynumber2 | Policynumber3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123A | 234 | 445 |
| 2 | 999 |  |  |
| 3 | 111 | 222 |  |

My final stage is then to concatenate all of the policy numbers from the multiple columns into a single field with a '; ' as  separator per customer e.g.

| Client_id | Policynumbers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123A ; 234 ; 445 |
| 2 | 999 |
| 3 | 111; 222 |

I've tried looking at a number of youtube videos but have never used the pivot function and can't seem to achieve the desired affect.  This needs to work across circa 2 million rows of data.

Any suggestions that can be offered are much welcome as I'm hitting a bit of a roadblock on this and beyond my knowledge. Any shortcuts to simplify this to 2

Comment: dynamic is almost always dynamic sql, but you need t o tag the correct rdms you are using

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is Sql Server MS 2017

Answer (score 1):

Try this script against your source data (ie the first table shown in your question - no intermediate table needed):

```
SELECT Client_id, STRING_AGG(Policynumber,'; ') as Policynumber
FROM <your table>
GROUP BY Client_id
```

Comment: You can add `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Policynumber ASC)` to guarantee the list is in a particular order. Ref. [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#f-generate-a-sorted-list-of-emails-per-towns)